# Youtube API: Link google client with youtube channel if status getIsLinked is false

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm able to get a list of google client channels and determine if channel linked with youtube or not using:

```
$response = $youtube->channels->listChannels('status', array('mine' => true));
$isLinked = $response[0]->getIsLinked();
```

But how do I link the channel if it is not linked? How do I make the channel privacy public?